# Wordpress database: add value of custom field to beginning of post (and save it combined)

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get the value of a custom field (`_subtitle`) from the post meta and have it saved to the beginning of the post text (post_content).

How can I achieve this? (I tried the `update()` function but lost the post content before)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `get_post_meta()` it might look something like that if you want to place it within a template.

```
<?php
    $subs = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_subtitle',true);

    $post_content = get_the_content();

    echo $subs.$post_content;
?>
```

This would be the gist of it, you could also filter `the_content();` and place the code within the *functions.php*

Comment: thanks for the hint, I'll have to read about it. but echo is to simply display the two of them together (_subtitle+post_content) not to save them as a new (combined) post_content, right?

Comment: Yes , display only beside it would not be wise to save meta in content its sorts of breaks convention.

Comment: interesting, hadn't heard about that yet. but maybe that's the reason why there's nearly no information anywhere about how to combine field-values, like adding the value of a custom field to the post_content (even though I would imagine the combination of fieldvalues - inside one of the concerning fields - to be a common need). in this case it's just text that needs to be added to the rest of the text (since the subtitles are not supported by 3rd party software)...

Comment: Well its because the post_meta is associated with the post itself so what you want to really is just make sure the template display that meta where you want it be (design wise also). So the website keep a formal structure when it comes to display such data. If you combined them on post publish lets say then you would have to deal with it in the content in the future which isn't something you really want management wise. You want it in a separate box as to not potential disturb the contents structure.

Comment: I see. the sad thing is just that my custom field is containing the teaser text for each article  - it's for a news site - and since the subtitle-field isn't well recognized by a number of other plugins and parties (f.e. mailpoets drag'n'drop editor doesn't recognize them,..) i need to get back to wordpress standard, get the text from the subtitles into the post_content and then grab the teaser from there via (theme built in) excerpt-function...

Comment: Actually most plugin will recognize it if you add it as a shortcode within your content. So lets say you add a shortcode to the content body of your post it will likely be outputted when the plugin queries your post content. 
`https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode`. What you can also do is create filters most plugin dev add documentation to which filter u want to override add additional information.